# I can't locate a folder in my duplicity backup

Tags: deja-dup, restore, duplicity

I've been backing up data with **deja dup**. I've asked it to back up two folders: my home folder, and `/media/D/data/`. My D drive flamed out several weeks, and I've let backups run.
I got a new hard drive and did a full restore to a folder on my new drive. It's just restoring my home folder and none of the files from my D drive.

I've used duplicity's list contents command and it only lists files from my home folder. I'm really confused- I don't know if the backups from D were never performed, or if duplicity deleted all the files from the D drive since it didn't see the drive anymore.

Any suggestions on how to find or recover the files from D?

Answer (score 1):

If a backup occurred, and the drive was not plugged in, the files on the drive would have been marked as deleted in the backup. The files are still in the backup. But you'll only recover them if you restore from a backup date when the drive was actually plugged in.

I recommend that you plug in some other drive named D. Then navigate to /media/D/ in the Files app. Right click on the white background and choose 'Recover missing files' or some such. It will search your backup for files at that path from any time in the past. It should show the 'data' folder from the last time it was backed up.